# How to use currency exchange rates library "Swap" with XAMPP localhost

Tags: php, class, composer-php

I want to use a library called [Swap](http://swap.voutzinos.org/), I've downloaded the directory in a ZIP file from Github and extracted the files to htdocs/swap on my machine... then, created index.php file that looks like this:

```
<?php
include ('src/Swap.php');
include ('src/Builder.php');

use Swap\Builder;

$swap = (new Builder())
    ->add('fixer')
    ->add('yahoo')
    ->build();
// Latest rate
$rate = $swap->latest('EUR/USD');

// 1.129
echo $rate->getValue();

// 2016-08-26
echo $rate->getDate()->format('Y-m-d');

// Historical rate
$rate = $swap->historical('EUR/USD', (new \DateTime())->modify('-15 days'));
?>
```

It's not working and I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Swap\Service\Factory' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\swap\src\Builder.php on line 137

why i'm getting this error and what i'm doing wrong?

When I'm trying to use composer to install it, I'm getting an error...
How can I avoid this?

Comment: The key is the autoloader. You'll need to find/implement a PSR-4 capable one. Composer has one so that's the easiest way to do it. Alternatively you can do the good old `require ...php` for each file you need to use and each of their dependencies.

Comment: do the installation using composer, and then `require` composer's autoloader.

Comment: Tried via terminal and got this:

`Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package florianv/swap No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by florianv/swap[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.`

Comment: Try setting `"minimum-stability": "dev",` in your composer.json, and also maybe add `"florianv/swap": "^3.0",` to your require section.

Comment: tried to edit composer.json but It's also says:
`Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` I'm missing something there?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used [GIthub Project](https://github.com/florianv/swap)
and yes this issue occurs when you do not use composer after donwloading the project, you need to run

```
Composer install
```

To get all the dependent libraries and need to write in the code as well,

```
include ('vendor/autoload.php');

use Swap\Builder;

// Build Swap with Fixer.io
$swap = (new Builder())
    ->add('fixer')
    ->build();
....
```

The output would be like

```
Array
(
    [Exchanger\ExchangeRatevalue] => 1.159
    [Exchanger\ExchangeRatedate] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2017-11-08 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

)
```